# How can I pass new lines to an argv parameter when IFS is set to something, the way command output does here?

Tags: c, unix, argv

How can I pass new lines to an argv parameter when IFS is set to something, the way command output does here?

Note, i'm doing this as a test to try to figure out how things work in unix. Not that i'd actually want new lines in an element of argv!

I have this program that shows argv.

```
$ cat blah.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int i = 0;
        while (argv[i]) {
                printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
                i++;
        }
        return 0;
}

$


$gcc blah.c -o blah
$
```

I notice that if I set IFS equal to something, or even just `IFS=` or IFS=`\n` Anything other than the default `unset IFS` So, e.g. IFS="{" then command output expansion gives multiple lines set to one argument e.g. to argv[1]

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/aaa$ IFS="{"
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/aaa$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/aaa$ ./blah `find .`
argv[0] = ./blah
argv[1] = .
./blah
./blah.c
./b
./a
```

Now if I try to pass arguments to ./blah, then I can't get multiple lines in argv[1] ! (which i'm interested in doing, as a test)

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/aaa$ ./blah "g h"
argv[0] = ./blah
argv[1] = g h
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/aaa$ ./blah g h
argv[0] = ./blah
argv[1] = g
argv[2] = h
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/aaa$ ./blah g\n h
argv[0] = ./blah
argv[1] = gn
argv[2] = h
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/aaa$ ./blah "g\n h"
argv[0] = ./blah
argv[1] = g\n h
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/aaa$
```

So, what is `find .` expanding to, that is leading multiple lines to get sent to argv[1] ?

Such that I can't reproduce the phenomena when I try to pass arguments to a program?

Comment: What if your program is *not* started on a command line? e.g. with [QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) in some GUI application?

Comment: To address my question, and looking at isaac's answer, one could do  `./blah abc$'\n'def`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When IFS doesn't contain spaces (white space) expansions on the command line desn't get split on such spaces:

```
$ var="Hello world"
$ set -x; printf '%s\n' $var; set +x
+ printf '%s\n' Hello world
Hello
world
+ set +x
```

As you can see from the (`+`) output (the `-x` output) the argument `$var`, one argument, gets split on spaces, and then printed as several arguments.

If IFS gets changed:

```
$ IFS=o
$ set -x; printf '%s\n' $var; set +x
+ printf '%s\n' Hell ' w' rld
Hell
 w
rld
+ set +x
```

The number and value of arguments also change.

What happens with `find .` is that when IFS contains an newline, yes, the default value of IFS should contain a newline:

```
$ printf '%s' "$IFS" | od -tcx1
0000000      \t  \n
         20  09  0a
0000003
```

the output of find . (which include several newlines) is divided on newlines (effectively, newlines get removed)

```
$ printf '<%s>\n' `find .`
<.>
<./hello>
```

If only one file called `hello` exists in the present directory (pwd).

But, if the newline inside IFS gets removed, the output is not divided, and it is only **one** string (that contains newlines, yes):

```
$ IFS=x
$ printf '<%s>\n' `find .`
<.
./hello>
```

Similar in effect to quoting the expansion of `find ,`:

```
$ IFS=$' \t\n'                  # return IFS to default in bash.
$ printf '<%s>\n' "`find .`"
<.
./hello>
```

So, to answer the initial question on the title:

> 

Just use the correct quotes:

```
$ var='hello world
and some other'
$ printf '<%s>\n' '$var' "$var" $var
<$var>
<hello world
and some other>
<hello>
<world>
<and>
<some>
<other>
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks. You say "the default value of IFS should contain a newline:"  And you demonstrate with printf and od. But If I try this from ubuntu `unset IFS; printf '%s' "$IFS"| od -tcx1` it displays 
`0000000`

Comment: Well, yes, if you unset a variable, it becomes empty. Try: `bash -c 'printf "%s" "$IFS"| od -tcx1'`. The call to a clean new bash instance will reset the value of IFS to its default value.

Comment: And, before you ask: there is an special case for an unset IFS, it acts as if it were at the default value of `space, tab, newline`. @barlop But in general, an unset variable becomes empty.

Comment: Thanks. I see  that besides the shift+ENTER to starta new line manually,  this also gets a new line in there   `./blah abc$'\n'def`  and it works in echo too without the -e  like `echo abc$'\n'def`  I see that echo -e is interpreting 5c6e as new line. but given an actual new line character echo even without -e will see it.